# Postgres select tables by date period with date-format table name

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using postgres to join tables with date-format names like:
business_202201
bueinsee_202202
...
business_202212 (these are table names under schema)
The join is up to the selected date period, e.g., if I select '2022-05-01' to '2022-07-15', the query will join three tables: bueinsee_202205, bueinsee_202206, bueinsee_202207

I know how to join one table using the below code
`

```
    cross join generate_series( timezone( @Timezone, @StartDate::date ) 
          , timezone( @Timezone, @EndDate::date ) + interval '1 day - 1 second'
          , '30 minutes'::interval ) dd
    join quantity.business_{@StartDateText} dmd 
        on (dmd.businessid = bp.businessid and dmd.demanddate = dd)
```

`
But in terms of looping among more than 1 tables, I have no idea how to make the results.
I want to ask for advice on this, thanks in advance

If my sample code is not the optimal solution, can suggest other wayout too.

Comment: You should have a partitioned table, then Postgres will do this automatically for you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, the joined table is dynamic that is dependent on the selected month. That's the hardest part in my query

Comment: If you use a partitioned table that is partitioned by month, then this gets as simply as using the correct WHERE condition.